# Mail from another server

Tags: aix, mailx

On my development UNIX server mail server is not installed. I want to mail a file everyday which I create on development server.

Now I am doing it manually by copying file to another UNIX server where mail server is installed and mailing that file.

Is there any way that I can connect (may be through shell script) to server where mail server installed from development sever to mail the file.

Both my servers are `AIX`

I know it is not an good question to ask but just a hope. Please close this question if it is not valid

Comment: copying can be automated (?) e.g. `scp local.file remote:/path/to` and also sending e.g. `ssh remote "mail joe@exemple.com < /path/to/local.file"`

Comment: @Archemar copying I am doing by sftp through shell script. But I want to mail the file

Comment: You don't need a mail *server* to send mail; just a properly configured mail client.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller Then I do not have mail client in my development server :(

Comment: I you can `sftp`, you probably can `ssh`